# Etherscan shows my contract has RPC errors

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, tokens

I deployed my token contract using Remix. I tested it in Ropsten several times and all was well. When I finally went to deploy it on the mainnet it deployed fine so it seemed. But in etherscan it doesn't show my token name or anything. It just has the contract address and when you hover over it it says, "There were RPC errors" and that it is, "Unable to determine if contract"

What's going on?

Comment: What is your contract address? Did you check with them if it was a temporary glitch?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having this issue in the future, the problem wasn't with me, it was with Etherscan so save your money. They were having a syncing problem and after 3 days everything showed up. All is well.